# Jquery datepicker highlight specific dates fetched from ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using jquery date picker (http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) in my page. In the page I have a dropdown for program list. Beside the dropdown there is a textbox on clicking which will open the datepicker. I select the any program from dropdown and fire an ajax to fetch program dates .I am able to high light those dates in the datepicker when the user clicks the textbox.

Now my problem is if I select any program whose dates is available then the datapicker is highlighted. For second time for other program which program date is not available still highlighted. I am using  beforeShowDay() method to highlight specific dates.

The main problem which I am able to debug is the javascript variable in my case "datesArray" is not reset inside the  beforeShowDay() method each time I call ajax.

Here is my code

```js
$("#resourceId").change(function() {
  var datesArray = [];
  $.ajax({
    url: '/aptcare/getscheduledate.action',
    data: "resourecid=" + $(this).val(),
    method: "POST",
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
      strarr = $.trim(data).split(",");
      for (var i = 0; i < strarr.length; i++) {
        datesArray.push(strarr[i]);
      }
    }
  })

  console.log("dates array: " + datesArray);

  $('.datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      var theday = date.getDate() + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getFullYear();
      console.log("to highlight array: " + datesArray);
      return [true, $.inArray(theday, datesArray) >= 0 ? "Highlighted" : ''];
    }
  });

})
```

Here are the console logs

For the **first case dates array**: `"12/11/2013,12/11/2013,22/11/2013"`

and to **highlight array**: `"12/11/2013,12/11/2013,22/11/2013"`

For the **second case dates array**:

and to **highlight array**: `"12/11/2013,12/11/2013,22/11/2013"`

That is **"datesArray"** is not reset.

Thank you advance for your help.

Comment: `async : false` = bad; using `POST` for getting data =  bad.

Comment: @moonwave99 Ok I will change my method to GET but async : false is required in my case.

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/UkLh2/2/

Comment: @TuhinSubhraDey it is not, just do your business in the success callback ^^

Comment: I tried replacing the datepicker code in success callback but no success. Don't know why "datesArray" is not set every time inside "beforeShowDay" method